# Product of characteristic functions, counter example

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, characteristic-functions

We know that for independent random variables $X,Y$ we have: $\varphi_{X+Y}(t)=\varphi_X(t)\cdot \varphi_Y(t)$.

Now I'm searching for an example that shows that the reversal of the statement is not true, so I want $X$ and $Y$ which fulfill $\varphi_{X+Y}(t)=\varphi_X(t)\cdot \varphi_Y(t)$ but are dependent.

I can't think of an example that shows this.

Comment: The question at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3184336/varphi-xyt-varphi-xt-cdot-varphi-yt-but-x-and-y-are-not-independ gives an example

Answer (score 0):

Consider the characteristic function of $nX$, $n \in \mathbb N$. We have

$$
\varphi_{nX}(t) = \int_\mathbb R e^{itx}f_{nX}(x)dx.
$$
$f_{nX}(x) = f_X(\frac{x}{n})$ and so
$$
\varphi_{nX}(t) = \frac{1}{n}\int_\mathbb R e^{intx}f_X(x)dx = \frac{1}{n}\varphi_X(nt)
$$

To find a counter example, it is sufficient to find a distribution for $X$ such that
$$\varphi_X(t)^n \neq \frac{1}{n}\varphi_X(nt).$$
Take, for example, the normal distribution.